# Mdoify LIS Such that a element is greater than sum of all elements before

Tags: algorithm, sorting, set, dynamic-programming, lis

> Suppose an array = {2,5,7,8,10}. You need to find the length of Longest Increasing Sub-sequence such that a element is not less than the sum of all elements before it.

In this case the answer can be {2,5,7}, {2,5,8} or {2,8,10}. So Length = 3
This is easily solvable in O(n^2). As LIS Length can be found in O(n log n). As the problem is asking only the length, so, I think this problem is also solvable in O(n log n). But how can I do that?

Comment: What are the constraints on the values of the array? Can they be negative?

Comment: @kraskevich No they all are positive ...

Comment: Are they arbitrarily large? Are you fine with something like `O(N * log MAX_VALUE)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need a DP Solution at all.
First sort the numbers in non-decreasing order. And loop from left to right. keep track of the current sum.
If next number is not-less than the sum add it to LIS. else proceed to next number.
It can be proven that the greedy solution is the optimal solution. Prove it yourself ;)

Comment: original array: {10, 1, 2}; sorted: {1, 2, 10}.
Result of the loop: {1, 2, 10}.
Solution?: {10, 1, 2}

Are You sure this is correct?

Comment: @TymurGubayev ow. I Thought he is asking for selecting some element. :( Then this greedy solution will work.    
Like this problem - https://dmoj.ca/problem/tle16c4p1   
This is solvable using this :)

Comment: @RezwanArefin Aren't you a contest programmer? I see your name in NHSPC rankings every year. Remember who I am? The one who had accused of posting a duplicate of your question in Math SE.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Yes I am that RezwanArefin :3 But I can't remember you :3

Comment: @RezwanArefin https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066356/y2-fracx5-1x-1-x-y-in-mathbbz, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070615/formula-for-calculating-the-total-number-of-solution-pairs-to-an-equation

Answer (score 0):

1. There's an `O(N^2)` dynamic programming solution which goes like:

   - Let `f(i, j)`  be the smallest sum that a "correct" subsequence ending in one of the first `i` elements and consisting of exactly `j` elements can have.
   - The base case is `f(0, 0) = 0` (empty prefix, no elements)
   - The transition are `f(i, j) -> f(i + 1, j)` (not adding a new element) and
     `f(i, j) -> f(i + 1, j + 1) if a[i] > f(i, j)` (adding the `i`-th element to the end of the subsequence if we can).

The correctness of this solution is self-evident.

2. A cool fact: let `A` be a "correct" subsequence of `k` elements. Than the last element of `A` is not less than `max(1, 2^(k-2))`(proof: it's the case for `k = 1` and `k = 2`. Now we can use induction and the fact that `1 + sum i = 0 .. k of 2^k = 2^(k+1)`)
3. Thus, `j` ranges over `0..log MAX_A + C` in the dynamic programming solution described above, so it works in `O(N * log MAX_A)`.

`O(N * log MAX_A)` is not `O(N log N)`, but this solution can be good for practical purposes.

Comment: Didn't understand the solution clearly .. But this will work .. (y)

Comment: Nope... This will not work... 
N <= 10,000
arr[i] <= 10^9 
o.O

Comment: @user7337803 It will. 10^4 * log 10^9 is a very small number. In fact, a properly implemented `O(N^2)` with linear memory will work in a very small (less than 1 sec) amount of time.